# How can I check Image Source from Button defined on XAML in Code Behind?

Tags: .net, wpf

I have the following button in xaml:

```
                        <Button name="MyButton1">
                            <Image Source="MyImage/star.png"/>
                        </Button>
```

I need to access the Image Source from Code behind to check it it is "start.png"

I tried to cast:
`(ImageBrush)MyButton1.Background`  but I got exception cuz it returns SolidColorBrush instead, I'm confused.

any tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this by doing:

((System.Windows.Controls.Image)MyButton1.Content).Source.ToString()

Answer (score 1):

Give the Image a name:

```
                   <Button name="MyButton1">
                        <Image Source="MyImage/star.png" Name="MyButton1Image"/>
                    </Button>
```

Then you can use "MyButton1Image.Source" to get the file name of the image.